# Question about Complete partially Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: graphs

I am reading CPDAG, can anyone please explain why G1 and G3 are not equivalence classes as in the picture below?
Thank you very much!

according to https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume18/acid03a-html/node2.html .

> "Theorem 1 [59]   Two DAGs are equivalent if and only if they have the
> same skeleton and the same v-structures.
>
> The skeleton of a DAG is the undirected graph that results from ignoring the directionality of every edge.
>
> A v-structure in a DAG $H$ is an ordered triplet of nodes,
> $(x,y,z)$, such that (1) $H$ contains the arcs  $x\rightarrow y$ and
> $y \leftarrow z$, and (2) the nodes $x$ and $z$ are not adjacent in
> $H$. A head-to-head pattern (shortened h-h) in a DAG $H$ is an ordered
> triplet of nodes, $(x,y,z)$, such that $H$ contains the arcs
> $x\rightarrow y$ and  $y \leftarrow z$. Note that in an h-h pattern
> $(x,y,z)$ the nodes $x$ and $z$ can be adjacent."
>
> The concept of equivalence of DAGs partitions the space of DAGs into a set of equivalence classes.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain/define the term CPDAG in your post? Also what do you think yourself, why aren't G1 and G3 in equivalence class, any idea?

Comment: It's also weird why you ask "why $G_1$ is not in class $G$" when I can read on the fine prints under the picture saying $G_1$ is in class $G$.

Comment: Thank you. I added the description in the question. Please have a look. Thank you!

Comment: What is a CPDAG? (You've expanded the acronym but not given a definition.) What does "equivalent" mean?

Answer (score 3):

They have different v-structures: $G_1$ has the v-structures $(x_3,y,x_4),(x_4,y,x_3)$, whereas $G_3$ has the v-structures $(x_1,x_4,y),(y,x_4,x_1)$.

Comment: Thank you, however, I can say so with G1 and G4 (but the example said that G1 G4 are in its equivalence class): "$G_1$ has the v-structures $(x_3,y,x_4),(x_4,y,x_3)$ whereas $G_4$ has the v-structures $(x_1,x_4,y),(y,x_4,x_1)$". So why are they sill equivalent?

Comment: It could be a typo. Ask the authors.

Answer (score 1):

This answer includes some clarification and an answer. The figure in the question is from [here](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-228). Some clarifications regarding the terms:

1. Two DAGs are equivalent iff they have the same skeletons and the same v-structures. Each equivalent class can be uniquely represented by a partial DAG (PDAG).
2. An equivalence class is denoted using a completed partially directed acyclic graph (CPDAG). Given a DAG, to find its equivalence class, keep the v-structures and convert every other directed edge to undirected, except those that may lead to new v-structures when reversed.

Coming back to the question, in the paper where the image comes from, it seems to be a typo. Also, I don't think that G is a CPDAG since it has directed edges not participating in any v-structure.

---

References

[1] David Maxwell Chickering, "Learning Equivalence Classes of Bayesian-Network Structures", JMLR (2002)

[2] Guido Consonni, "Learning Markov Equivalence Classes of Directed Acyclic Graphs: an Objective Bayesian Approach", https://www.hiit.fi/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Learning-Markov-Equivalence-S29.pdf